# How can I get this for-comprehension to return?

Tags: scala, playframework, future, for-comprehension

I'm creating a controller that talks to a service. The controller (which is based on the Play library `AbstractController`) takes an implicit request and returns a `Future[Result]`. The service receives a request and returns a `Future[Model]`. I have some conditions that I want to guard against model creation. For example, if the user does not have access then no model should be created.

```
 def create(): Action[JsValue] = Action(parse.tolerantJson).async { implicit request: Request[JsValue] =>
    val modelOpt: Option[Future[Result]] =  // I've tried Future[Result] here too
      for {
        attributes <- (request.body \ "data" \ "attributes").validate[JsObject].asOpt
        userOpt = (request.body \ "data" \ "attributes" \ "user-name").validate[String].asOpt
        user <- userOpt
        model <- service1.createModel(user) // Create Model returns type of Future[Model], so this should flatMap to Model
      } yield {
        val permission = checkPermission(user)  // Returns true or false, depending on if the user is permissioned
        (userOpt, permission) match {
          case (Some(_), true) => Ok(model)
          case (Some(_), false) => Forbidden
          case (None, _) => NotFound 
          case (_, false) => Forbidden 
        }
      }

    modelOpt.getOrElse(Future { InternalServerError })
  }
```

However, the compiler complains saying that it expects an `Option[Future[Result]]` and it received a `Future[Result]` (likely because of my supplied type for `modelOpt`). However, I think if the Json fails to validate it will give me `None`, so I think that the outer type *does* have to be an Option. Can anyone show me what's going on?

Comment: It might help if you could reduce your code to a [mcve]. Tangential: `Future { InternalServerError }` doesn't fail with an InternalServerError; you want `Future { throw InternalServerError }` or, better, `Future.failed(InternalServerError)`.

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: if service1.createModel(user) return Future[A], and other from comprehension return Option[T] it doens't copmpile `cause you should use only same monoids.

Comment: I don't think Future.failed will work because `InternalServerError` is not throwable. @BrianMcCutchon

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the signature of method [getOrElse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#getOrElse[B%3E:A](default:=%3EB):B) in trait `Option[A]`:

```
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
```

it unwraps `Option` to return a `A` or its supertype up to `B`.

Now, with modelOpt an `Option[Future[Result]]`, applying `getOrElse` with a given default value of type `Future[Result]` (or its subtype) would result in a `Future[Result]`.

Similar to how `getOrElse` works but keeping `Option` in place, method [orElse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#orElse[B%3E:A](alternative:=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]) has the following signature:

```
final def orElse[B >: A](alternative: => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

Thus, applying `orElse` to modelOpt like below would return the wanted `Option[Future[Result]]`:

```
modelOpt.orElse(Some(Future.successful(InternalServerError)))
```

Note that [Future.successful](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#successful[T](result:T):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) is being used to provide an already completed Future with the specified result.